# Data got corrupted and unable to open a excel file after i export to excel in angular

Tags: angular, exceljs

Able to to export an excel file in angular using exceljs and filesaver. 
But when i open a file nothing was displayed . I am using excel 2013. Since i want to format the data and make the alignment during export im using exceljs.

Performed `npm install` and imported like this for exceljs and filesaver below

```
    import * as Excel from "exceljs/dist/exceljs.min.js";
    import * as ExcelProper from "exceljs";
    import * as fs from 'file-saver';


    generateExcel() {

        //Excel Title, Header, Data
        const title = 'Car Sell Report';
        const header = ["Year", "Month", "Make", "Model", "Quantity", "Pct"]
        const data = [
          [2007, 1, "Volkswagen ", "Volkswagen Passat", 1267, 10],
          [2007, 1, "Toyota ", "Toyota Rav4", 819, 6.5],
          [2007, 1, "Toyota ", "Toyota Avensis", 787, 6.2],
          [2007, 1, "Volkswagen ", "Volkswagen Golf", 720, 5.7],
          [2007, 1, "Toyota ", "Toyota Corolla", 691, 5.4],
          [2007, 1, "Peugeot ", "Peugeot 307", 481, 3.8],
          [2008, 1, "Toyota ", "Toyota Prius", 217, 2.2],
          [2008, 1, "Skoda ", "Skoda Octavia", 216, 2.2],
          [2008, 1, "Peugeot ", "Peugeot 308", 135, 1.4],
          [2008, 2, "Ford ", "Ford Mondeo", 624, 5.9],
          [2008, 2, "Volkswagen ", "Volkswagen Passat", 551, 5.2],
          [2008, 2, "Volkswagen ", "Volkswagen Golf", 488, 4.6],
          [2008, 2, "Volvo ", "Volvo V70", 392, 3.7],
          [2008, 2, "Toyota ", "Toyota Auris", 342, 3.2],
          [2008, 2, "Volkswagen ", "Volkswagen Tiguan", 340, 3.2],
          [2008, 2, "Toyota ", "Toyota Avensis", 315, 3],
          [2008, 2, "Nissan ", "Nissan Qashqai", 272, 2.6],
          [2008, 2, "Nissan ", "Nissan X-Trail", 271, 2.6],
          [2008, 2, "Mitsubishi ", "Mitsubishi Outlander", 257, 2.4],
          [2008, 2, "Toyota ", "Toyota Rav4", 250, 2.4],
          [2008, 2, "Ford ", "Ford Focus", 235, 2.2],
          [2008, 2, "Skoda ", "Skoda Octavia", 225, 2.1],
          [2008, 2, "Toyota ", "Toyota Yaris", 222, 2.1],
          [2008, 2, "Honda ", "Honda CR-V", 219, 2.1],
          [2008, 2, "Audi ", "Audi A4", 200, 1.9],
          [2008, 2, "BMW ", "BMW 3-serie", 184, 1.7],
          [2008, 2, "Toyota ", "Toyota Prius", 165, 1.6],
          [2008, 2, "Peugeot ", "Peugeot 207", 144, 1.4]
        ];
        //Create workbook and worksheet
        let workbook: ExcelProper.Workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
        let worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('Car Data');
        //Add Row and formatting
        let titleRow = worksheet.addRow([title]);
        titleRow.font = { name: 'Comic Sans MS', family: 4, size: 16, underline: 'double', bold: true }
        worksheet.addRow([]);
        // let subTitleRow = worksheet.addRow(['Date : ' + this.datePipe.transform(new Date(), 'medium')])



        worksheet.mergeCells('A1:D2');
        //Blank Row 
        worksheet.addRow([]);
        //Add Header Row
        let headerRow = worksheet.addRow(header);

        // Cell Style : Fill and Border
        headerRow.eachCell((cell, number) => {
          cell.fill = {
            type: 'pattern',
            pattern: 'solid',
            fgColor: { argb: 'FFFFFF00' },
            bgColor: { argb: 'FF0000FF' }
          }
          cell.border = { top: { style: 'thin' }, left: { style: 'thin' }, bottom: { style: 'thin' }, right: { style: 'thin' } }
        })
        // worksheet.addRows(data);
        // Add Data and Conditional Formatting
        data.forEach(d => {
          let row = worksheet.addRow(d);
          let qty = row.getCell(5);
          let color = 'FF99FF99';
          if (+qty.value < 500) {
            color = 'FF9999'
          }
          qty.fill = {
            type: 'pattern',
            pattern: 'solid',
            fgColor: { argb: color }
          }
        }
        );



    worksheet.getColumn(3).width = 30;
        worksheet.getColumn(4).width = 30;
        worksheet.addRow([]);
        //Footer Row
        let footerRow = worksheet.addRow(['This is system generated excel sheet.']);
        footerRow.getCell(1).fill = {
          type: 'pattern',
          pattern: 'solid',
          fgColor: { argb: 'FFCCFFE5' }
        };
        footerRow.getCell(1).border = { top: { style: 'thin' }, left: { style: 'thin' }, bottom: { style: 'thin' }, right: { style: 'thin' } }
        //Merge Cells
        worksheet.mergeCells(`A${footerRow.number}:F${footerRow.number}`);
        //Generate Excel File with given name
        workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer().then((data: any) => {
          let blob = new Blob([data], { type:"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" });
          fs.saveAs(blob, 'CarData.xlsx');
        })

  }
```